# Resuming apt-mirror fails due to corrupt index files

Tags: apt-mirror

I have problems to get `apt-mirror` to resume after is has been terminated abrupt (my VPN connection was terminated).

I get an error that indicates that some `apt-mirror` files are corrupt. Maybe the index files? I have tried to remove all the downloaded files, but that does not work.

The error output look like this:

```
$ sudo apt-mirror
Downloading 24 index files using 5 threads...
Begin time: Fri Sep  5 09:36:09 2014
[5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Fri Sep  5 09:36:09 2014

Proceed indexes: [P
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
P
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
P
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
P
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
]

0.0 bytes will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 0 archive files using 0 threads...
```

I have found a few answers on the net, but none of them helps. I would like to know where these gzip files are stored. Then it should be possible to remove them and the restart the apt-mirror stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple, but it took a while for me to figure it out. I had to remove `apt-mirror` and all of its configuration files etc.

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove apt-mirror
```

Some errors was reported where not empty directories was left, i.e. `dkpg` reported some errors.

I then removed the directories like this:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/spool/apt-mirror
```

Note that there could be other directories that fails to be removed. Thus you have to check the output from the first command.

Comment: what is the point to remove apt-mirror? you are not using it anymore? or you re-installed it again?

Answer (score 3):

Solution for "...gzip: stdin: not in gzip format...":

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit version.
You need to delete "skel" folder ONLY than run apt-mirror again!

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/spool/apt-mirror/skel/
$ apt-mirror
```

I don't know why but it works for me.

Comment: This actually solved the issue for me, but also downloaded additional 30 gigs, no idea what it downloaded or where it put them ... :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this script fixed my issue https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/113

Check the modified version of the script (scroll down)

**UPDATE** with details.

I used the script posted by rinnaz. Saved that as a *.sh file and ran it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# combined solutions for apt mirror from: https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/49,https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/102
# I had to create this file, in order to solve the issue of not downloading DEP-11 @2 files
# so all what I'm doing is running apt mirror manually, then downloading the other icon files every time
# Grep will grep the line starting with "set base_path"
# then we trim all extra white spaces
# then we cut the string by delimiter white space and take third value

dataFolder=$(grep -F "set base_path" /etc/apt/mirror.list | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f3)
echo "Base Folder path set in /etc/apt/mirror.list is: $dataFolder"
apt-mirror
echo 
echo -n "Do you want to Check MD5 Sum and Download Failed (auto Y in 5 seconds)? [Y/n]"
echo
read -t 5 answer
exit_status=$?
if [ $exit_status -ne 0 ] || [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ];then
    FAILEDPACKAGES=""
    echo "Reading and Checking MD5 checksum using file: $dataFolder/var/MD5"
    #cd $dataFolder/mirror
    rm -f FAILED_MD5.txt
    echo "Failed File will be stored in: $(PWD)/FAILED_MD5.txt"
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #echo "Checking: $line"
        sum=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
        filename=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
        echo "$sum $dataFolder/mirror/$filename" | md5sum -c -
        RESULT=$?
        if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ];then
            echo "$dataFolder/mirror/$filename" >> FAILED_MD5.txt
            wget -O $dataFolder/mirror/$filename $filename
            echo "$sum $dataFolder/mirror/$filename" | md5sum -c -
            SUBRESULT=$?
            if [ $SUBRESULT -ne 0 ];then
                echo "Sorry failed checksum again for file: $dataFolder/mirror/$filename"
                $FAILEDPACKAGES+="$dataFolder/mirror/$filename      Failed again, sorry cannot help"
            fi
        fi
    done
```